# Intel VGA drivers not compatible?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, vga, windows-installation

I have just done a format to a PC, and I have installed Windows XP.  However I have some problems with the screen (probably the refresh rate). When I move a window, it shows the window to move really slowly, and when I scroll, it scrolls very very slowly.

My motherboard is an Intel Desktop Board and the model of the motherboard is DQ965GF. The Device Manager, shows that Video Controller, and Video Controller (VGA Compatible) drivers are missing. So, I went to download them by Intel's support page [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop+Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+965+Express+Chipset+Family+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Desktop+Board+DQ965GF).

When I try to install the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for 963/965 Chipset-based Intel Desktop Board, I get the message, "Error: This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software. Setup will exit.".

The minimum requirements of the driver is for the PC to have at least 1GB of system memory (my PC has 3GB), enough hard disk space in the  (my hard disk is almost empty), and to have some specific models of intel chipsets (I have the chipset).

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem? I have been searching for a solution for about two hours now...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Some programs won't install if the resolution is low. (Seems kind of ironic doesn't it?) If you don't have the driver, windows might be defaulting to an extremely safe resolution.

Comment: wow! I have heard this for the first time. I will increase the resolution now, and try again:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intel has a utility to automatically detect and update drivers and software.

Product support page: [Intel® Desktop Board DQ965GF](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/dsktpboards/dq965gf)

As well to look for more information on the error look in `C:\Intel\Logs\`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As it shows, this tool, finds the drivers already installed, and it updates them. I have tried it about an hour ago, and it just informed me, that I do not have a graphics driver installed ;))

Comment: Thank you very much. The log file, show the message "ERROR 0x7FB: No INFs found that match the active deveices on the system"

Comment: Long shot: You don't happen to have a graphics card connected and the Intel graphics disabled in BIOS do you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to install the driver through the intel utility, you can always install the driver manually.

Find where the installer extracted the files (usually to C:\Intel)
Right click on the .inf file and click 'install'
Go to device manager, find your video card, tell it to search automatically for drivers.
It should then install.

If that fails, you can install right click on the video card in device manager and specify the exact .inf file to install.

Lastly, try windows update. Install a generic driver, then reboot and try the Intel driver again.

Here is a support document from Microsoft that further explains how to manually install drivers

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927524